# How to restrict download of specified file types

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I want to restrict my web app so that .txt files can not be downloaded/shown.
Is this something I can set up in my web.config file?

I tried this in my config file:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.txt" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

...but it had no effect. I am using IIS7 and application is .NET3.5, could this have something to do with it? I know this would actually work for .NEt 1.0 1.1 and 2.0.

I noticed in the documentation for this ([add httpHandlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d6sws33.aspx)), the **Requirements** section:

> Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) version 5.0, 5.1, or 6.0
> The .NET Framework version 1.0, 1.1, or 2.0
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2003 or Visual Studio 2005

...which indicates that this is not supported in .NET 3 and IIS7...

Where is this specified in IIS7?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at this MS Support article on how to achieve this: [HOW TO: Use ASP.NET to Protect File Types](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815152).

It involves setting up IIS to forward those requests to ASP.NET and then setting up your web.config to block the desired file types, such as: (nb this works for your dev machine and before IIS7 - be sure to see below)

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.ini" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

According to the [httpHandlers Element page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bya7fh0a(v=vs.85).aspx), the following extensions are forbidden by default as of .NET 2.0 (.ini is not one of them):

*.asax, *.ascx, *.master, *.skin, *.browser, *.sitemap, *.config, *.cs, *.csproj, *.vb, *.vbproj, *.webinfo, *.licx, *.resx, *.resources, *.mdb, *.vjsproj, *.java, *.jsl, *.ldb, *.dsdgm, *.ssdgm, *.lsad, *.ssmap, *.cd, *.dsprototype, *.lsaprototype, *.sdm, *.sdmDocument, *.mdf, *.ldf

**EDIT:** this applies to IIS versions prior to IIS 7.0. IIS 7.0 adds an additional operating mode, called Integrated Mode (default for ASP.NET), which requires handlers to be placed in `<system.webServer>/<handlers>` instead of `<system.web>/<httpHandlers>`. I added some more info and links to @awe's answer on this page, check it out for more details.

**IMPORTANT! for IIS 7.0 or later**

As specified in the edit you need to place the `<add>` element in a different place *and the rule needs a name too* - if you dont specify a name you will get a 500 Internal Error when restarting

```
  <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="IgnoreIni" verb="*" path="*.ini" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this, but it doesn't work **:(** . I have changed my question to include your answer since this does not work either, but it is exactly what I want to work... Could it be that IIS7 does not respect this? Is it some settings in IIS7 that needs to be cahnged for this to work? My app is .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 6):

OK. I found out the problem. In **.NET 3**, this specified in a different section of the web.config file. Instead of `<system.web><httpHandlers>`, it is in `<system.webServer><handlers>` like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="NoTxtAllowed" verb="*" path="*.txt" 
       type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Although this is the answer that did the trick for me, I have marked the answer from **Ahmad Mageed** as ***the*** answer, as he provided it before I added the version information for .NET 3 in my question. He also pointed me in the right direction to find the solution. Note that his answer is correct for all versions of .NET prior to 3.

**EDIT:** IIS 7.0 supports 2 modes, Integrated and Classic. Integrated is the default mode for ASP.NET apps on IIS 7.0 which require handlers to be placed in `<system.webServer>/<handlers>` instead of `<system.web>/<httpHandlers>` (this is supported by the Classic mode and prior IIS versions).

Helpful links regarding this issue:

- [How to: Register HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx)
- [Moving an ASP.NET Application from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515251.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Integration With IIS 7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/243/aspnet-integration-with-iis7/)

Comment: @awe: +1, thanks for sharing. Some more info according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx - "For IIS 6.0, you register the handler by using the httpHandlers section of the Web.config file. For IIS 7.0 running in Classic mode, you register the handler in the httpHandlers section, and you map the handler to the Aspnet_isapi.dll file. For IIS 7.0 running in Integrated mode, you register the handler by using the handlers element in the system.WebServer section." ASP.NET on IIS 7.0 runs in Integrated Mode by default.

Comment: Great. Thanks for adding more info about this.

Answer (score 2):

This is something you set in IIS, but it should be there by default already.

Comment: You are right. ini files are already restricted. I was just picking an example, but was more interested in the principle, and if it was possible to do this in web.config in the application.

Comment: Can you point to where in IIS7 configuration this can be changed/added new etc..?

Comment: I suggest using the answer provided above, because that is app specific. in IIS you just remvoe the MIME type, but hten the filetype won't be seerved on the entire web server anymore, in any website running on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change these to .config? or .aspx?