# Detect if file is loaded directly or embedded via page

Tags: security, iis, directory

Is it  possible to know .mp4 in accessed from directly with full URL or loading in source of page? I want to restrict direct loading/downloading of mp4 files. I am using IIS8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restrict download of specified file types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362898/how-to-restrict-download-of-specified-file-types)