# Restrict download for general files in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I need to restrict client access to some specific files. I would like to do it in my web.config instead of relying on who manages the IIS.

I know it is possible to restrict access to file types (for example, all XML files), as seen here: [How to restrict download of specified file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362898/how-to-restrict-download-of-specified-file-types)

However, how to specify exact file(s)? For example, I would need to block direct access to the file at ~/test/mytest.xml
Keep in mind that another copy of this file, located at ~/secondtest/mytest.xml should still be available to the client.

The only option is in IIS? I can't control it in the web.config?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly specify the file name like following in web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="test/mytest.xml" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

For IIS7 onwards use following.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add path="test/mytest.xml" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" name="XML"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict access from logged in, anon, specific roles, etc to paths and/or files in your web.config as such:

```
  <location path="filename or path">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

You might also need to put the following in your config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I tried, this doesn't work for XML files apparently.

Comment: updated with an additional config value - that might do it though I guess it could depend on your current IIS config and version (I'm a bit unclear on what the provided solution is valid for... worked for me though)

Comment: FYI, this has a typo (the <system.webServer> tag is missing a forward slash for the closing tag). I tried to edit it, but it said "Suggested edit queue is full".